# Error when calling read function with Ethers.js HELP!

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I'm getting a:

`Error: call revert exception (method="balanceOf(address)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL\_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.4.0)`

Whenever I call a read-only function using Ethers.js. I've been looking everywhere for hours & I can't figure out why it's not working. It lets me send write transactions, but I can't make a simple read-only call.

```
async function enableEth() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const [account] = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_requestAccounts'
    });
    const signer = provider.getSigner(account);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        contractABI,
        signer
    );

    const result = await contract.balanceOf(
        '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3'
    );
    console.log(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your contract is deployed and/or to the right location i.e. `--network localhost`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error `call revert exception` means that:

- Method reverts during its execution.
- Method is not present in your contract.
- Contract not deployed on the network you're connected to (or address put is incorrect).
- Your network has some temporary outages.

The third one is a frequent dev error, and it's likely also the reason for you.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out I was deploying to `hardhat` instead of `localhost`

Comment: This thing. I restarted my local node, yet forgot to deploy the contract again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not specific to this issue, but I had exactly the same error, for me it was that my JSON-RPC endpoint was not working. And multiple different ones were not working, so you should try a few.